# how to undertand the result of mongostat?

Tags: mongodb

when I use  mongostat  ,it  shows  insert  query & etc ...

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize  res qrw arw net_in net_out conn set repl                time
 27985    *0     *0     *0     217   440|0  4.3% 79.9%       0 2.47G 598M 0|0 1|1  4.69m   8.01m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:23.423
 23750    *0     *0     *0     193   393|0  5.5% 78.2%       0 2.47G 599M 0|0 1|1  4.05m   7.01m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:24.417
 26240    *0     *0     *0     208   433|0  3.6% 79.2%       0 2.47G 591M 0|0 1|1  4.38m   7.60m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:25.417
 27490    *0     *0     *0     227   451|0  5.7% 82.7%       0 2.47G 602M 0|0 2|0  4.56m   8.01m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:26.418
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     5|0  3.2% 79.2%       0 2.47G 612M 0|0 1|0   621b   16.9m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:27.418
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0     6|0  3.2% 79.2%       0 2.47G 612M 0|0 1|0  1.15k   71.7k   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:28.419
 20994     2      3     *0     169   353|0  4.8% 80.7%       0 2.47G 613M 0|0 1|0  3.52m   5.98m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:29.419
 28202    *0     *0     *0     250   501|0  6.4% 81.1%       0 2.47G 599M 0|0 1|0  4.76m   8.33m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:30.417
 29650    *0     *0     *0     227   453|0  2.7% 78.2%       0 2.47G 596M 0|0 1|0  4.94m   8.57m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:31.436
 26487    *0     *0     *0     213   440|0  4.8% 80.3%       0 2.47G 593M 0|0 1|0  4.44m   9.37m   20  wh  PRI Dec 17 14:41:32.441
```

What does these parameters represent?
What are the two parts seperated by `|`  in `command`  `qrw`  `qre`  ？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a explained in the docs, but only implicitly. After a bit of digging I came to this result:

The fields `qrw` and `arw` are a combination of `qr` + `qw` and `ar` + `aw` with the following meanings:

> qr: The length of the queue of clients waiting to read data from the MongoDB instance.
>
> qw: The length of the queue of clients waiting to write data from the MongoDB instance.
>
> ar: The number of active clients performing read operations.
>
> aw: The number of active clients performing write operations.

All fields are described in the official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#fields

Comment: What does *0 mean in the query column? I am getting similar value in my mongostat but I am pretty sure that we don't have zero queries. Any help would be appreciated.